# write() creating partially readable / corrupt files

Tags: python, linux, file-io

I have a long string (DNA sequence with \n at regular intervals) that I'm trying to write to a file.

Writing with the code below, I have a file that cannot be fully accessed by getline in a C++ program- that is, istream seems to think the file only has about a dozen lines. Likewise, if I do cat or more on the file I only see about a dozen lines of the file. *However,* if I open the file with an editor (like gedit) the whole file is there, and if I resave I'm suddenly able to read the whole thing.

```
  output = open(fileFasta, 'w')
  lines = vSeq[1].split('\n')
  # Tried this
  output.write(vSeq[1])
  # And this
  for line in lines:
    output.write(line)
    output.flush()
  output.close()
```

I'm obviously not finishing the file in some important way that gedit does. Ideas?

Comment: try looking at your file with something like `od` or a hex editor.

Comment: Any suggestions what to look for? Opening with od it all seems to be there.

Comment: Actually I take that back: od also seems to only retrieve about a dozen lines worth of bytes.

Comment: This is very unusual. What does `ls -l` say about the size of the file? Does it match the output of `cat`, `od` etc?

Comment: Ahh, your hint led me to the problem: used ghex to discover my source file has carriage returns (\r) instead of newline characters (\n). Thanks! If you post a solution I'll give ya the credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used ghex to discover my source file was using carriage returns (\r) instead of newline (\n) characters.

Comment: Always hex dump a file if you want to be certain of its contents.  Printing it out to the console is not reliable if it contains certain binary stuff (such as raw carriage returns, backspaces, and NUL bytes).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your C++ program don't flush the output stream enough. Or perhaps there is a null byte somewhere...

Comment: That doesn't sound like an answer, but some questions you could pose in comments.